# How to get list of memberships whose start date is between a date range?

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-entity

I am trying to filter a list of memberships based on start dates. My filter consists of From date and To date. I want to get a list of memberships whose start date is between From and To date.

I am using a angular page with wordpress setup. Here is what I have tried so far with no success.

```
var membership = crmApi('Membership', 'get', {
          status_id: 2, // get memberships with status Current
          start_date_low: "2016-08-13",
          start_date_high: "2017-08-12",
          return: ['contact_id', 'membership_name', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'source']
        });
return membership;
```

Comment: worth changing your comment to an answer imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done [@petednz - fuzion](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/96/petednz-fuzion)

Solved it. I have used this. `start_date: {"BETWEEN":["2016-08-13", "2017-08-12"]}` Have got the info from support > Developer > API Explorer. I am a newbie in CiviCRM. Was not aware of such a helpful API Explorer.

Comment: I can't get this to work in the V4 API Explorer. Turns the array into a string ->addWhere('start_date', 'BETWEEN', ['["2021-05-11 00:00:00"', '"2021-05-11 23:59:59"]']). Any idea the correct way to enter the datetime range in the V4 explorer?